# How do you know when a View was tapped but its child wasn't?

Tags: react-native

For example if you wanted to close the modal when the gray background (anywhere outside the middle white box) is tapped:

[image]

```
  containerOnClick(e) {
    if (isNotInsideChildView(e)) {
       closeModal()
    }
  }

<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  onPress={this.containerOnClick}
  >
  <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}
    >
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        padding: 10,
      }}
      >
      <Text>dkfj</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the child in a `<Touchable*>` component. Descendent Touchables (even without an `onPress` prop) block the `onPress` from happening to ancestor Touchables inside the descendent's boundaries.